# Trying to find a way to SUM a field based on criteria looked up in different table in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

See below tables for data. I am trying to answer the question "What is the total QTY of items classified as Fruit?" in a singular formula.

Table 1

| Product | QTY |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 5 |
| Apple | 2 |
| Banana | 3 |
| Carrot | 5 |

Table 2

| Product | Class |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Fruit |
| Banana | Fruit |
| Carrot | Veg |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

[image]

Formula in `G1`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((VLOOKUP(A2:A5,D2:E4,2,0)="Fruit")*(B2:B5))
```

Answer (score 0):

with SUMIFS instead of VLOOKUP:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,D2:D4)*(E2:E4="fruit"))
```

[image]